# Homepage blocks not displaying after update to 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, upgrade

I just updated my Magento to 1.9.3.1 and so far I've noticed the blocks on my homepage in both the main content and the sidebar content are not displaying at all. They were displaying before the update just fine. I've noticed people saying to try adding permissions in `System > Permissions > Blocks`, but that page is missing in my backend. Is that page not available in 1.9.3.1?

Comment: do you have root admin account ?

Comment: I have an administrator account. Is there a difference between a root admin account and an admin account?

Comment: yes If your role does not have permisssion then you can not see that menu links

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I got it working. I had to reinstall the SUPEE 6788 patch. After I reinstalled it the page `System > Permissions > Blocks` reappeared. I was then able to add the blocks that weren't displaying in the permissions list.